# is there a way to allow a phone "-" in phone format using numeric in vuelidate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I'm using vuelidate to validate a form in VUE build. I have a phone number input that needs to be formatted as 222-222-2222 which I have setup using a phone mask. My issue is now the input will not validate when the phone is filled in. My error message is still displayed. Is there a way to allow for numbers only along with a dash "-"???

```
  <div class="form-field">
        <label for="phone">
          Phone Number
        </label>

        <input type="text" class="form-input text-input" name="phone" id="phone" @input="phoneNumberMask()"
               v-model.trim="$v.formData.phone.$model">

        <label v-if="($v.formData.phone.$dirty && !$v.formData.phone.required)
          || ($v.formData.phone.$dirty && !$v.formData.phone.numeric)
          || ($v.formData.phone.$dirty && !$v.formData.phone.minLength)
          || ($v.formData.phone.$dirty && !$v.formData.phone.maxLength)" class="error">
          Please enter a valid phone number.
        </label>
      </div>


    validations: {
      formData: {
        phone: {
          required,
          numeric,
          minLength: minLength(12),
          maxLength: maxLength(12)
         }
        }
       }

methods: {
  phoneNumberMask(){
        const x = this.formData.phone.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
        this.formData.phone = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '-' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    },
   }
```

Comment: You can provide a regex validator to a validation, see https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-regex-based-validator

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you can create a regular expression that validates you phone number format, in this case `/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/` could be a starting point.

Here a complete example.

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <label
      :class="{
        error: $v.number.$error,
        green: $v.number.$dirty && !$v.number.$error
      }"
    >
      <input
        class=""
        v-model="number"
        @change="$v.number.$touch()"
        placeholder="Phone number"
      />
    </label>
    <div class="" v-if="$v.number.$dirty && $v.number.$error">
      <p class="">NOT VALID</p>
    </div>

    <button
      class="
        "
      :disabled="$v.$invalid"
      @click="saveClick()"
    >
      <span class="">Save</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script part

```
import { required, helpers } from "vuelidate/lib/validators"

const number = helpers.regex(
  "serial",
  /^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/
)

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      number: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    serial: {
      get() {
        return this.number
      },
      set(value) {
        this.number = value
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveClick() {
      //TODO
    }
  },
  validations: {
    number: {
      required,
      number
    }
  }
}
```

### Note

This is for Vue 2.x and vuelidate `^0.7.6`

Comment: clearer: instead of [0123456789] use [0-9]